# How to use the local macro to do ZonalStatisticsAsTable in batch

Tags: arcpy, statistics, batch, zonal-statistics

I have a series of files named as 'rawfile200101', 'rawfiles200102',...,'rawfile201104'.  I want to do ZonalStatisticsAsTable for each of them with names corresponding to the time of the raw files, such as 'newfile200101', 'newfiles200102',...,'newfile201104'.  I know how to script it for individal file, but I am trying to do it in batch.  I wrote the following codes for four files, it is always shown error that "I:/rawfile%list%.tif" does not exist.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

yrmn = ['200101', '200102', '200103', '200104']

for list in yrmn:
    outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable("I:/boundaries", "ID", "I:/rawfile%list%.tif", "I:/newfile%list%.dbf", "DATA", "SUM")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python won't substitute variables like `%list%` into strings like how ModelBuilder does. Here's the most basic way to do it in Python using string concatenation:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

yrmn = ['200101', '200102', '200103', '200104']

for list in yrmn:
    in_value_raster = "I:/rawfile" + list + ".tif"
    out_table = "I:/newfile" + list + ".dbf"
    outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable("I:/boundaries", "ID", in_value_raster, out_table, "DATA", "SUM")
```

You could also use [string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
    in_value_raster = "I:/rawfile%s.tif" % list
    out_table = "I:/newfile%s.dbf" % list
```

Python purists would prefer the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), since the above string formatted [may be deprecated in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12382738/1254992):

```
    in_value_raster = "I:/rawfile{}.tif".format(list)
    out_table = "I:/newfile{}.dbf".format(list)
```

Comment: I used the last one and it works.  dmahr, you are a time saver.  Thx a lot.

Comment: @user25458 Sure thing. Be sure to mark the question as answered if you're all set.